# Render different JS file on each page refresh?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Doing a game in Pixi.JS and I need to know if it's possible to render a different JS file on each page refresh. I'll have the js file names stored in an array, and would like to iterate through the array and render the indexes js file each time the page refreshes. I'm using vanilla Javascript, is this possible?

Comment: Everything's possible I suppose. Could you please show us your attempts to achieve this?

Comment: Found this link, might be what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770296/load-different-js-files-for-different-pages-or-load-together, will do @Kyll

Comment: You could drop a cookie then increment the value every time the cookie is read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is achievable.

Store the  counter locally,increment it till the length of the array and based on the current counter value load the js.

refer http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

[Conditionally load JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521343/conditionally-load-javascript-file)

Comment: Any chance of an example?